# How do I install JDK 17 on my AWS AMI Ec2 instance?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, java-17

I need to install *JDK 17* on my *AWS EC2 AMI* instance.

Is there any command? Any answers would be appreciated!

Comment: JDK 17 from which vendor? Here are the instruction to install Amazon Coretto: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-17-ug/generic-linux-install.html

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi There was a much easier way to install Corretto 11 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/amazon-linux-install.html I believe the AWS team is working on implementing this for Corretto 17. See this: https://github.com/corretto/corretto-17/issues/19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Install with package managers:

### `deb`-based distros (such as `Debian` or `Ubuntu`)

```
# Download deb package from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/
# And then
sudo dpkg -i jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.deb
```

### `rpm`-based  distros (such as `RHEL` or `CentOS`)

```
# Download rpm package from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/
# And then
sudo rpm -i jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.rpm
```

## Any distro without or with differrent package manager

Download [x64 Compressed tar.gz Archive](https://download.oracle.com/java/17/latest/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz) 
from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/

Create `jvm` directory

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
```

Change to the directory.

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm
```

Extract  `jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz` to that directory.

`~/Downloads/` - is a directory where archive is saved.
If your downloaded file is in any other location, change the command according to your path.

```
sudo tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz
```

Enter the following command to open the environment variables file.

```
sudo ${EDITOR} /etc/environment
```

Edit your ${PATH}

```
# Add this to the $PATH variable
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin
```

Add the following environment variables at the end of the file.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17"
```

Inform the system about the Java's location.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java" 0
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/javac" 0
sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/java
sudo update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17/bin/javac
```

To check version:

```
java -version
```

Comment: This answer assumes that OP wants and can use Oracle JDK. This is likely not the case.